# numpy array to list formatting

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How would i format a numpy array of form

```
data1 = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])
```

to a list in this format:

```
data = [
       [[0,0], [0]],
       [[0,1], [1]],
       [[1,0], [1]],
       [[1,1], [0]]
    ]
```

I tried using two for loops

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(3):
       if j == 2:
            va[i] = data1[i][j]
       else:            
            sa[i] = data1[i][j]
```

but that gives me an index out of bounds error. I would love some ideas on how to go about this

Comment: what are `va` and `sa` initialized to?

Comment: @hpaulj `va = []` and `sa = []` but thank you. I got an answer to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension and slicing:

```
>>> data1 = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])
>>> print [[x[:2].tolist(), x[2:].tolist()] for x in data1]
[[[0, 0], [0]],
 [[0, 1], [1]],
 [[1, 0], [1]],
 [[1, 1], [0]]]
```